# How to make my website responsive to mobile

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here is the link to my website , on the laptop is working fine, but on mobile phone its not responsive. Here is the link to my site https://ticketsoko.co.ke/
and the follwing is how its showing on mobile phone . Is there a way on mobile phone it can resize the images and be viewed the same as its showing on desktop.
[image: This when viewed on mobile phone]

This is when I view it from the desktop.
[image]

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<meta name="viewport"-->
    <!--      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">-->
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/logoo.png"/>
    <title>Click & Pay | TicketSoko</title>  
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700%7COpen+Sans" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" -->
           <!-- integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- Resource style -->
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style3.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>


<nav class=" navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">

     <ul>
         <img class="logo" src="img/logoo.png" alt="logo" style="height: 100px; width:250px; float:right;">
      </ul>

</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
     <div class="carousel-inner">
          <br><br><br>
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/image1.jpeg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%; height:500px;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%; height:480px;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%; height:480px;">
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Bootstrap, which is a good start, read more about responsive design using Bootstraps grid system. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see you used width as 250px. So it'll always take the 250 px of any screen whether it's a small screen or big screen. 
Example for if you designed this website on a screen which is having 250px width only then it'll render completely on the screen. And if you'll run it on the big screen then also it wil take only 250 px and rest pixels will not be rendered.

So you should use the `percentage for the widths`. Like if you want to draw a component from left to right and 50% of the screen. Then give the width as 50%. Like that you can make it responsive. 
And you can use media query too. Just read about the media query too.

Hope this will help you.